# Change json field name on api controller answer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, decorator

Let's say I have a controller with a get method:

```
[HttpGet]
public Car Get()
{
    return new Car() { Color = "Yellow" };
}
```

And also defined the Car class

```
public class Car {
   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "TheColorIs")]
   public string Color {get;set;}
}
```

The client is receiving something like this in json format:
{
    "Color": "Yellow"
}
Why isn't the property name in the json response "TheColorIs" ?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are using ASP.NET Core 3.x which using `System.Text.Json` instead of `Newtonsoft.Json` . So that you should use `JsonPropertyNameAttribute` Class from `System.Text.Json.Serialization` namespace :

```
public class Car
{
    [JsonPropertyName("TheColorIs")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please accept as answer which may help others who meet same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the Attribute type does not match to your serializer type, just like you use System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer, but you use Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty.